# How to convert week-days into hours in laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, php-carbon

1-If any user enter 1w2d in input field.

2-Value in this input field should get converted to total hours.

3After that I have to insert these total hours in database.

4When I will fetch total hours from  database it should return 1w2d.

Possible notation are that there is one Input field named as Estimated time where user can enter 1w2d or 1W2D .This should get converted into total hours.After that I have to send it into database.

*I am feeling helpless.I don't know what to do.I know how to convert week 
into hours but don't have any idea that how to convert 1w2d into hours.

Comment: Can you update your post with all possible notations in your input field? I think it's a really weird way to input data. Is it not possible to use a datepicker or a something like `<input name="weeks" type="number">` and `<input name="days" type="number">`?

Comment: Or maybe supply an input mask which you can simply split afterwards. Btw. this has nothing to do with Laravel in particular.

Comment: I have mentioned possible notation in detail section

Comment: I suggest you look up the standard formating strings provided by [PHP's `DateInterval` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). It's very similar to the kind of thing you're looking for, and it's build directly into PHP already. The notation is slightly different, but close enough that it should prove helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function convertWDHtoHours($data) {

  preg_match_all('/(\d+[wW]+|\d+[dD]+|\d+[hH]+)/', $data, $matches);
  $hours = 0;
  foreach($matches[0] AS $match) {
    switch(true) {
      case preg_match('/\d+[hH]+/', $match) :
        $hours += (int)$match;
        break;

      case preg_match('/\d+[dD]+/', $match) :
        $hours += (int)$match*24;
        break;

      case preg_match('/\d+[wW]+/', $match) :
        $hours += (int)$match*24*7;
        break;
    }
  }
  return $hours;
}

print "23h => ".convertWDHtoHours('23h')."<br/>";
print "20d => ".convertWDHtoHours('20d')."<br/>";
print "2W => ".convertWDHtoHours('2W')."<br/>";
print "1D2h => ".convertWDHtoHours('1D2h')."<br/>";
print "1w2H => ".convertWDHtoHours('1w2H')."<br/>";
print "1w2d => ".convertWDHtoHours('1w2d')."<br/>";

?>
```

Here is result:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ioj02x

Comment: how to insert it into database

Comment: you regex is not working .Showing error preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

Comment: Take the code from result link. It's working. Maybe somewhere I've forgot delimiter, find the line of error and add delimiter at the end of regex.

Comment: thanks .You are gem dude.You understood my problem and gave me a right answer.Thanks a lot man.What I have to do if I want to convert total hours into weekdayshours

Comment: To convert hours to AwBdCh format: function convertHoursToWDH($hours){ $weeks = (int)($hours/(24*7)); $hours -= $weeks*24*7; $days =(int)($hours/24); $hours -= $days*24; return $weeks.'W'.$days.'D'.$hours.'H';}

Comment: if we are inserting 20h then it is sending 0 in database.What to do now

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi updated my answer. Have to work. Look at result link.

Comment: thanks @num8er.Tell me also how to generate preg_match.Please share tricks to make own preg_match

Comment: There is no trick. I write them myself. I've learned regular expressions from manuals. For quick-start I recommend You to read this: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html or search Youtube: php regular expressions tutorial